# How Can I Combine 'SRM' and 'Find'?

Tags: find, secure-erase

I'm using SRM to securely delete files and directories.  Most of the data is on FAT and NTFS volumes since I dualboot with Windows (I'm trying to use Ubuntu as much as possible and stay away from Windows).

However every now and then I run into an error `Error: File <filepath> - file is hardlinked 1 time(s), skipping!` which I discovered means there's a hardlink to the file.

I did some searching and found the NON-srm way to delete all linked files is with the command (example:) `$ sudo find ~ -xdev -samefile '/home/USERNAME/Desktop/hardlinks (copy).txt' | xargs rm`

Unfortunately the above doesn't work if I replace "RM" with "SRM"...

```
Error: File /home/USERNAME/Desktop/hardlinks - No such file or directory
Error: File (copy).txt - No such file or directory
Error: File /home/USERNAME/Desktop/links.txt - file is hardlinked 1 time(s), skipping!
```

[image]

Is there a way to achieve the same result: search for hard links for a specific file, then process them through **SRM**?
Preferably with the arguments **-rvz** (recursive, verbose, overwrite with zero)?

***note:** I also tried appending `-print0` to FIND and/or `-0` to XARGS which didn't help*